# pass argument to app by D-click in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, file-association

i did association to .plmx extension file to be opened in my app by D-click.
I want my form application can be launched by any package with .plmx extension, it doens't open any file when I double clicked on an associated file. It just invokes my app with initial form.
How to access my own extension file and read the content of this file.
how to read and display this file into my main form by double clicking the file?

when i write "`console.log(process.argv);`" i don't see my file shown.

How to solve that one?.Thank you in advance.

all the app is written in javascript!

my main.js starts like that:

```
app.on('ready', function () {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code my best guess would be that your association is just launching myapp.exe which would launch your app in its default state. To have it open with the file that was double clicked the association would need to pass the filepath into the executable as an argument so that the program knows which file it was opened with.

For example, double clicking on file.plmx would run the command

```
myapp.exe file.plmx
```

Once launched, the application would need to look at its arguments and load the given file.

Comment: You are right what you say, it just launching .exe file. but how do i pass the filepath (and where?)?

Comment: @TomCohen how exactly did you set up the file association?

Comment: i set it up via HKEY_CLESSES_ROOT + ChangesAssociations=yes

mabye i don't succeed because i use electron ?

Comment: This answer might be useful http://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with

Comment: it's not working.
when i write:
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
  console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
});

the file i open is not shown